# Thread Locked - Epollwait running over Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I have realized that all `GenericThreadPoolEventProcessorWorker` thread in an application is RUNNABLE state with Epollwait,
Something is wrong with this state that task size in a queue is increasing over time where GenericThreadPoolEventProcessorWorker threads pulling task from. 
Do you have an idea where application stuck?

```
Using weblogic 12.1.2 , openstack4j  2.0.9


"GenericThreadPoolEventProcessorWorker" #12665 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3b7005e800 nid=0xe9f5 runnable [0x00007f398c1a5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000006ab039fd8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000006ab039fc0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000006ab03acb0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.readInternal(NIOInputStream.java:146)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.read(NIOInputStream.java:90)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.read(NIOInputStream.java:73)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x00000006ab14d158> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:310)
    at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:232)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:554)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:688)
    - locked <0x00000006ab14d220> (a weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:41)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1545)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpCommand.execute(HttpCommand.java:86)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invokeRequest(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:65)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invokeRequest(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:70)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:56)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:33)
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:189)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:183)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.internal.TenantServiceImpl.get(TenantServiceImpl.java:29)
```

Comment: What was the root cause of this issue?

Comment: do not remember , 7 years passed :)